# Can't handle SIGTERM in Heroku app when deploying via docker

Tags: docker, heroku, sigterm

I am migrating an existing Heroku application to deploy with Docker instead of git. The application is using a custom SIGTERM handler which doesn't get called on dyno termination.

The SIGTERM handler works fine when deployed via git, but fails to run when deployed via Heroku.

Here's the appropriate line from my Dockerfile:

```
RUN exec python3 main.py
```

(I've already tried without `exec`, however it doesn't seem to matter.)

The dyno gets stopped immediately with a status code 143. There is no sign of the signal handler ever getting fired.

This issue is similar to [this one](https://help.heroku.com/ROG3H81R/why-does-sigterm-handling-not-work-correctly-in-nodejs-with-npm): I have a strange PID 1 process that has a different UID, which means I have no control over it. It's probably handling SIGTERM itself without letting the application know.

EDIT: The main process' command line is `sh -l -c 'sh -c python3\ main.py'`, or `sh -l -c 'python3 main.py'` if using `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD`.

Comment: Is `RUN exec python3 main.py` last line of your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Yes, it's the last line.

Comment: It's difficult to assist with "a strange PID 1". Please show a list of processes running inside your container of you have it. Keep in mind we can't see your screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

`ENTRYPOINT exec python3 main.py` as the last line of Dockerfile

Then python process would have pid 1 and receive SIGTERM.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. `ENTRYPOINT python3 main.py` doesn't start at all, while `ENTRYPOINT /app/main.py` starts (with the shebang in main.py), but still can't handle SIGTERM.

Comment: please, share the full dockerfile and output of `ps -ef` inside the container after it starts

Comment: I finally managed to handle SIGTERM by replacing `/bin/sh` with my entry point. The `sh` process is present even if I use `ENTRYPOINT` (They probably do it that way to populate the environment with config vars).
I don't have `ps` in the container.

Comment: yes, i've edited my answer. `exec` should make python process to have pid 1 and not `/bin/sh`. And shebang should `/bin/python3` i guess

Comment: Unfortunately this also doesn't work. The dyno fails to start if i use `exec` with `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: you can show the processes running in the container using `docker top` and again, please share the `Dockerfile` if you want a serious answer. otherwise, we have to guess.... the answer provided should work in general case unless you do someting not standard in `Dockerfile`